# How to handle deprecated warning for CLOB_DURATION_SESSION

Tags: warnings, compiler-warnings, deprecated, clob

In my java code we have upgraded to latest ojdbc version in order to support JDK17, but started getting below warnings:

The field CLOB.DURATION_SESSION is deprecated.
The type CLOB is deprecated.
Don't want to use @Supresswarning.

I am trying to change import from oracle.sql.CLOB and trying to use java.sql.CLOB at below line:

clob = CLOB.createTemporary(cnx, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

Any help is appreciated.

Don't want to use @Supresswarning.
Tried to use CLOB concrete method but not able to resolve.

Any suggestion or reference is helpful

Comment: You said you are "trying to change import from oracle.sql.CLOB and trying to use java.sql.CLOB". Could you specify the problem (compiler error/warning, runtime error, unexpected behavior of program, etc.) or concern that you have?